# Possible to trigger Azure Devops Pipeline on any branch commit?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

To trigger pipeline for branches starting with "features/", I'd do:

```
trigger:
  - features/*
```

But is there a way to trigger for ALL branches? I've tried

```
trigger:
  - *
```

and

```
trigger:
  - /*
```

But neither work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like triggering by path instead of branch does the trick:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - /*
```

Or according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards), simply:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - '*'
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing and it will help other members a lot. Please consider [accepting it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that other members with similar issue could benefit from it. Thx!